# SQL code working in Access, but not in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I have the following SQL code which was generated by using the query design view in Microsoft Access.

```
SELECT tblLoan.BorrowerID, tblBorrower.BorrowerFirstName, tblBorrower.BorrowerLastName, tblBorrower.Address1, tblBorrower.Address2, tblBorrower.City, tblBorrower.ContactNumber, tblBorrower.DateOfRegistration, tblBorrower.Gender, tblBorrower.Email, tblLoan.LoanID, tblLoan.ReceivedBy, tblLoan.Fine, tblLoan.CostPerDay, tblLoan.OverdueDays, tblLoan.OverdueFine, tblLoan.AdminID, tblBookLoan.BookID, tblBookLoan.DateOut, tblBookLoan.DateDueBack, tblBookLoan.ReturnDate, tblBook.Title, tblBook.Author, tblBook.ISBN, tblBook.PublicationYear
FROM tblType INNER JOIN (tblBookType INNER JOIN (tblBookCategory INNER JOIN ((tblBorrower INNER JOIN tblLoan ON tblBorrower.[BorrowerID] = tblLoan.[BorrowerID]) INNER JOIN (tblBook INNER JOIN tblBookLoan ON tblBook.[BookID] = tblBookLoan.[BookID]) ON tblLoan.[LoanID] = tblBookLoan.[LoanID]) ON tblBookCategory.BookCategoryID = tblBook.BookCategoryID) ON tblBookType.BookTypeID = tblBook.BookTypeID) ON tblType.TypeID = tblBorrower.TypeID
WHERE (((tblBookLoan.DateDueBack)<Date()));
```

It is running fine in Access and returning the required records.

However, when I try to run the same code in Visual Studio using the Query Wizard, I get the following message:

Error in WHERE clause near ')'.
Unable to parse query text.

I have tried removing brackets, but nothing seems to work.

Why does it run in Access and not in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL server, the function to retrieve the current datetime is `GetDate()`